# Problems with Time across countries PHP

Tags: php, time

I am creating a website and display the time of all posts. The website is for users of all countries. Hence the timezone will be different. I am showing time in `ago` format.

**The problem is:** When a user posts time based on his timezone is saved in the database. When another user of another country login with different timezone, the `ago` format goes wrong.

Is there a solution to this?

My strategy is: Convert all time to a single time format that is based on a single timezone and then show in ago format.

Do this strategy works? Are there any problems(Not in my point of view)?

Comment: Save all times as UST for ease of use

Comment: Save all of the times in UTC, then store each timezone offset for each user.

Comment: If you are dealing with users from different timezones, it makes sense to get the time on the client rather then determining the timezone on the server

Comment: @atmd, The thing is PHP (server) cannot determine the users (client) timezone, it has to be specified. It's best to keep the server on one timezone, then apply an offset depending on which user is viewing the data.

Comment: @craig1231 yes that what I'm saying, once the user does what ever action causes a save, a timestamp is generated on the client side. The suggestion being that a user will have there computer configured to their own timezone. The server then doesnt kneed to concern itself with the timezone, just handle the timestamp